# Prevent to access parent component directly

Tags: angular-material, angular6, angular2-routing

I have those routes in one of my modules:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'public/intro', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'public', component: PublicComponent, data: { preload: true, delay: true, state: 'public' },
  children:
  [
    { path: 'intro', component: IntroComponent, data: { preload: true, delay: true, state: 'intro' },  },
    { path: 'explorar', component: ExplorarComponent, data: { preload: true, delay: true, state: 'explorar' }, },
    { path: 'cadastro', component: CadastroComponent, data: { preload: true, delay: true, state: 'cadastro' }, },
    { path: 'entrar', component: EntrarComponent, data: { preload: true, delay: true, state: 'entrar' }, },
  ]},
];
```

How do I prevent the user from typing for example:

localhost:4200/#/public

and accessing the parent component(public) directly?

I mean I would like to allow only those routes for this specific area:

localhost:4200/#/public/intro

localhost:4200/#/public/explorar

localhost:4200/#/public/cadastro

localhost:4200/#/public/entrar

Thing is, I have a router-outlet inside the PublicComponent.
I load the 4 children there.(toolbar with the routes buttons).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may achieve that using Componentless Routes, as described [here](https://angular.io/api/router/Routes#componentless-routes).

In your case, you would have something like:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'public/intro', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'public', children: [
    { path: 'intro', component: IntroComponent },
    { path: 'explorar', component: ExplorarComponent },
    { path: 'cadastro', component: CadastroComponent },
    { path: 'entrar', component: EntrarComponent },
  ]}
];
```

Comment: Interesting.
Thing is, I have a router-outlet inside the PublicComponent.
I load the 4 children there.(toolbar with the routes buttons).
(Sorry forgot to mention).